# Copy and Paste JSON between Visual studio html files

Tags: json, visual-studio-2013, copy, paste

I am trying to copy JSON from one .html file into another in Visual Studio 2013 with Update 4 and the pasted result is stripping all the : between JSON properties and values giving me useless markup.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading font-bold">Spline</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div ui-jq="plot" ui-options="
          [
            { data: {{d}}, points: { show: true, radius: 6}, splines: { show: true, tension: 0.45, lineWidth: 5, fill: 0 } }
          ], 
          {
            colors: ['{{app.color.info}}'],
            series: { shadowSize: 3 },
            xaxis:{ 
              font: { color: '#ccc' },
              position: 'bottom',
              ticks: [
                [ 1, 'Jan' ], [ 2, 'Feb' ], [ 3, 'Mar' ], [ 4, 'Apr' ], [ 5, 'May' ], [ 6, 'Jun' ], [ 7, 'Jul' ], [ 8, 'Aug' ], [ 9, 'Sep' ], [ 10, 'Oct' ], [ 11, 'Nov' ], [ 12, 'Dec' ]
              ]
            },
            yaxis:{ font: { color: '#ccc' } },
            grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true, borderWidth: 0, color: '#ccc' },
            tooltip: true,
            tooltipOpts: { content: '%x.1 is %y.4',  defaultTheme: false, shifts: { x: 0, y: 20 } }
          }
        " style="height:240px" >
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

is being turned into:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading font-bold">Spline</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div ui-jq="plot" ui-options="
                         [
                         { data {{d}} , points { show true, radius 6}, splines { show true, tension 0.45, linewidth 5, fill 0 } }
                         ],
                         {
                         colors ['{{app.color.info}}'],
                         series { shadowsize 3 },
                         xaxis:{
                         font { color '#ccc' },
                         position 'bottom' ,
                         ticks [
                         [ 1, 'Jan' ], [ 2, 'Feb' ], [ 3, 'Mar' ], [ 4, 'Apr' ], [ 5, 'May' ], [ 6, 'Jun' ], [ 7, 'Jul' ], [ 8, 'Aug' ], [ 9, 'Sep' ], [ 10, 'Oct' ], [ 11, 'Nov' ], [ 12, 'Dec' ]
                         ]
                         },
                         yaxis:{ font { color '#ccc' } },
                         grid { hoverable true, clickable true, borderwidth 0, color '#ccc' },
                         tooltip true,
                         tooltipopts { content '%x.1 is %y.4' , defaulttheme false, shifts { x 0, y 20 } }
                         }
                         " style=" height:240px">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Big Question mark.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit complex json to put directly into an argument, but anyway... if you press once undo after pasting, you can undo the auto formatting attempted by Visual Studio. Your semicolons will be restored too.

Comment: It's is a proof of concept angular app hence complexity - I'll give you a point on this as it does indeed work - I should have been more explicit - I'm looking for a solution/plugin that allows/forces Visual Studio to recognise JSON in the source editor.